# How to grant access to authenticated users in Tomcat 5.5.x?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, servlets

I'd like to be grant access to authenticated users in my web application without requiring them to be a member of a specific role.

My first guess was to specify `<role-name>*</role_name>` in my auth-constraint, however it seems that this just means grant access to any role defined in my web-app, not grant access to any authenticated user.

Is it possible to do this in Tomcat 5.5.x and if so how?

Comment: Why not just create a role for your application?

Comment: I'd like to know whether I must do that, or whether I can express 'grant to all authenticated users' as a constraint...

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, Tomcat does support this. In the server.xml, add [allRolesMode = authOnly](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.AllRolesMode.html)
in the appropriate Realm tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the direct answer is no, you can't do that in Java EE 5. But you could create an "everyone" role which every authenticated user is a part of. I think that's what John is getting at, and is how I would do it. It's really not much different.

Alternatively, if you're willing to do this programmatically, and are using container-managed authentication, you should be able to detect an authenticated user by checking whether HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() isn't null. That doesn't involve roles.